# Django efficient lookups: Related manager vs whole queryset

Tags: django

Let's say I have the following Django models:

```
class X(models.Model):
    some_field = models.FloatField()


class Y(models.Model):
    x = models.ForeignKey(X)
    another_field = models.DateField()
```

Let's say I'm looking for a particular instance of y, with a certain date (lookup_date), belonging to a certain x. Which option would be a more efficient lookup, if any?:

**1. Y.objects.get(x=x, another_field=lookup_date)**

or using the related manager:

**2. x.y_set.get(another_field=lookup_date)**

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you add `.query` to the end of those you'll find they might produce the same query. Either way, [race the horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: You are 100% correct, it's identical. I didn't know about .query. Is one of them considered more pythonic? You can put your comment in an answers than I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably find that they produce the same query, you can check this by adding `.query` to the end of the query which will show the resulting sql.

```
Y.objects.get(x=x, another_field=lookup_date).query
x.y_set.get(another_field=lookup_date).query
```

But either way this is a micro optimization and you may find it interesting to read [Eric Lippert's performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

> Is one of them considered more pythonic?

Not really, I tend to use the second since it can make it slightly easier to conform to pep8's line length standard

Comment: I also try to use the second option wherever possible because it provides a flow as well while reading. Especially if you use `related_name` with ForeignKey.

Comment: @AKS - I agree, I didn't add it to my answer since it is more of an opinion but it also makes the intent of the queryset clearer

Comment: @Sayse: I agree that it is opinion based and that's why I added this in comments :).

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the above code example do not work -- they will result in an error of type "x object has no attribute 'query'", because .get() returns a record instance, not a QuerySet, and .query is an attribute of a QuerySet. To use .query successfully, it must be used on a QuerySet or an expression returning a QuerySet. As shown above with get(), it will not work.

Comment: I encountered this problem then found out that one should change `get` to `filter` to use the `query` attribute.